# Seria possível sobrescrever o método with do Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Em partes da minha aplicação estou utilizando o seguinte `redirect`:

```
return redirect('/painel/posts')
        ->with(['error' => 'Ocorreu um erro ao tentar adicionar o post!']);
```

Seria possível no `App\Http\Controllers\Controller.php` sobrescrever o **with**, ou até mesmo em outro local fora do diretório Vendor?

Por exemplo, gostaria de sobrescrever para:

```
//Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
public function with($key, $value = null)
{
    //$key = is_array($key) ? $key : [$key => $value];

    $key = ['status' => $key, 'mensagem' => $value];

    foreach ($key as $k => $v) {
        $this->session->flash($k, $v);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Com isso no controller bastaria:

```
return redirect('/painel/posts')
        ->with('error','Ocorreu um erro ao tentar adicionar o post!');
```

Já na view ficaria assim:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-{{ session('status') }}">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        {{ session('mensagem') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Pois atualmente para obter o resultado acima sou obrigado a fazer assim:

```
return redirect('/painel/posts')
        ->with([
                 'status' => 'error',
                'mensagem' => 'Ocorreu um erro ao tentar adicionar o post!'
               ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Não, não pode sobrescrever esse método dessa maneira, mas, existe algo que pode ser feito na classe `Controller` que servirá de base para todos os `controllers` que herdam seu comportamento:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, AuthorizesResources, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function with($status, $message)
    {
        request()->session()->flash('status', $status);
        request()->session()->flash('message', $message);
    }
}
```

Utilizando em algum `controller`:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class SavePictureController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->with('status', 'message');
        return view('pictures');
    }
}
```

***Explicação:*** a linha `redirect('/painel/posts')->with()` no `with` é um [Session Flash](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#flash-data) e para isso funcionar e ter o mesmo comportamento tem que utilizar:

```
request()->session()->flash('status', $status);
```

Em [php](/questions/tagged/php) é complicado reescrever métodos, principalmente quando fazem parte do ***Core*** do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) já está pronto assim e não tem como ir na `classe` e simplesmente escrever outro método logo embaixo, não tem `overload` em `PHP` e a reescrita sendo feito com uma herança pode quebrar a estrutura do `Laravel`.

O único meio mais simples, objetivo e sem causar problemas é criar um `helper`, chamando esse outro `helper` `redirect`.

---

**Passos:**

Crie uma pasta `Helpers` dentro da pasta `app` do projeto [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel). Nela crie um arquivo chamado `helpers.php` em seu contéudo:

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('redirect_with'))
{
    function redirect_with($url, $status, $message)
    {
        return redirect($url)->with(['error' => $status,
            'message' => $message]);
    }
}
```

observe que o nome não pode ser igual ao que já existe, então, foi colocado `redirect_with`. ***Observação:*** pode criar quantas funções forem necessárias dentro desse arquivo `helpers.php`.

A aplicação tem que saber que esse arquivo `helpers.php` existe, precisa registrar no `composer.json` assim:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files":[
        "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

tem agora um **chave** `files` com o endereço do seu novo código de funções (`helpers`).

No *prompt de comando* digite: `php.exe composer.phar dump`, com esse comando irá registrar no `auto_load.php` da sua aplicação.

Sua utilização se torna simples a partir dai:

```
return redirect_with('/painel/posts',
                     'error',
                     'Ocorreu um erro ao tentar adicionar o post!');
```

É uma forma fácil que não compromete os códigos do `Core` do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel). O grande problema em fazer **reescrita** em métodos do `Core` e na hora das atualizações dos pacotes que serão todos perdidos pelas novas versões baixadas, a criação de funções `wrapper` seria a melhor forma de ***solucionar seu problema***.

Comment: Pensei em sobrescrever para não ter nem mesmo que utilizar "$this->".

Comment: @Fábio você está fazendo confusão e usar `$this->` em `PHP` é normal é da própria arquitetura. Outra coisa o `redirect('/painel/posts')->with` retorna um `session flash` e a única maneira seria essa. Você quer deixar isso padrão ?

Comment: Compreendi Virgilio. Vou explicar, queria sobrescrever o with, porém, manter parte de seu comportamento, desejo tão somente ao invés de passar um array, passar duas strings. Todo o restante do comportamento seria mantido. Porém, essa sobrescrita teria que ser fora do diretório Vendor. Sei que originalmente este código está em Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

Comment: Duvida: @Fabio: tem como reescrever, talvez, dá um trabalham desnecessário, mas, pode ser criado um `wrapper` um código que existe chamado por outro código melhorado. Como você chamaria isso? tem idéia?

Comment: Você deseja a criação de um `helper`?

Comment: Em teoria sim. Na prática a intenção era chamar redirect('/')->with('error', 'mensagem aqui'), já o método sobrescrito iria pegar essas duas strings e jogar para dentro de um array ['status' => $string1, 'mensagem' => $string2]

Comment: `redirect` não é uma classe é uma `function` que retorna a instância da `classe Request`, entendeu?

Comment: Para um melhor entendimento edite a pergunta

Comment: @Fabio, eu entendi o que você queria fazer, que é mexer no Core do Laravel, nunca faça isso, porque, pode atrapalhar as atualizações dos componentes. Faça um `helper` como eu te disse